# 128-bit Pseudorandom number Generator

Tags: random-number-generator

Is there any 128-bit pseudorandom number generator available?

I tried the [Blum Blum Shub Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub), but I can't produce a 128-bit pseudo-random number. 
Maybe before I produce a 128-bit pseudorandom number, I need to input a 128-bit prime number which is hard to determine.

Comment: Many mistakes here: a) in your [recent other question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3142/555) it is clear your need a TRNG. b) BBS generates 1 bit at a time, and can be called 128 times to generate 128 bits. c) BBS needs a _composite_ modulus that is hard to factor, and that implies primes much bigger than 128 bit. d) 128-bit primes are easy to get; follow this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NextPrime[2^127]) for the smallest one.

Comment: @fgrieu I think you can output more than one bit at a time with BBS: up to $log_2(n)$ lower-order bits where $n$ is the size of your modulus, in bits. So for a 2048-bit modulus that's 11 bits per iteration (but 8 is probably more convenient). Not that it would make much difference from a computational point of view.

Comment: @fgrieu I think it's a bit misleading to say he needs a true RNG. He needs a well seeded secure PRNG.

Comment: @Thomas: any source for that? The [HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap5.pdf), note 5.41, states that $j=c\lg\lg n$ bits can be used (where n is the modulus) but adds "an explicit range of values of $c$ for which
the resulting generator is cryptographically secure under the intractability
assumption of the integer factorization problem has not been determined".

Comment: @CodeInChaos: In order to seed the IV of OFB, we need not to repeat and not be influencable. A counter is fine. Being indistinguishable from random (the measure of security of a PRNG) is entirely optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BBS is probably the wrong choice for you needs.

AES in counter (CTR) mode will take a 128-bit key and produce 128-bits of output per iteration.

It also happens to be a lot faster than BBS.